# Messages from controller with accented characters not displaying properly when shown with ASP.MVC 5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

After some operations, i store some messages within the viewbag to be shown later like this:

```
if (BO == null)
{
    ViewBag.result = "Anexo do B.O obrigatório.";
    return View("SinistroLLPP", vm);
}
```

And then:

```
if (null != ViewBag.result)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert('@ViewBag.result');
    </script>
}
```

But my accented characters aren't shown properly. Instead of

```
"Anexo do B.O obrigatório."
```

I'm getting

```
"Anexo do B.O obrigat&#243;rio."
```

It happens with other characters as well. How can i solve this?

Comment: `alert(@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.result)))`

Comment: Spent a whole day trying different things when the solution was this simple....thanks man!

Comment: @StephenMuecke: Why is `Json.Encode` necessary? Isn't `Html.Raw` alone enough?

Comment: Actually, it *is* necessary in your code, on second look, because that's the only way to make it come out as a JS string. However, you could simply do `alert('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.result)')` (notice the use of single quotes). I suppose it's just a matter of taste which way you go.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you need cange cultureInfo value of the response:

```
if (BO == null)
{
    ViewBag.result = ("Anexo do B.O obrigatório.").ToString(new CultureInfo("it-IT"));
    return View("SinistroLLPP", vm);
}
```